# Sort output from `docker ps` in powershell while keeping table header at the top

Tags: powershell, sorting, stdout

In my powershell profile I have a shortcut to `docker ps`, with the format set to improve readability

```
function dps {
    docker ps --format "table {{.Names}}\t{{.ID}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Ports}}" | Sort-Object

    #     ????
    #    Tee-Object -Variable lines |
    #    select -first 1 |
    #    Write-Host;
    #    $lines | Sort-Object | Write-Host # Prints nothing
}
```

Sorting the lines in this way works nicely and groups my containers by name, but the table header ends up in the *middle* of the output.

You can see that I tried to separate out the first line of output (the header), but I couldn't figure out how to get the table to continue to print. How can I keep the table header at the top while sorting and printing the table?

*Sample Output*

```
database_A                27b33272e64c        Up 15 hours                       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
database_B                1b1662223f17        Up 15 hours                       33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33640->3306/tcp
database_C                8f98fc0890cc        Up 15 hours                       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
framework_A               a0d829729c8e        Up 15 hours (unhealthy)           5050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5170->80/tcp
NAMES                     CONTAINER ID        STATUS                            PORTS
service_A                 8708aec85ea7        Up 15 hours (healthy)             0.0.0.0:5100->8080/tcp
service_B                 7931365f450e        Up 15 hours (unhealthy)           5160/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5160->80/tcp
service_C                 e9b9272011d8        Up 15 hours (unhealthy)           5160/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5110->80/tcp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LotPing's answer was close but duplicated the header information. Combining it with Volodymyr's answer gives us this:

```
function dps {
  docker ps --format "{{.Names}}\t{{.ID}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Ports}}" |
  ConvertFrom-CSV -Delimiter "`t" -Header ("Names","Id","Status","Ports") |
  Sort-Object Names
}
```

This has the desired output! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to convert tab delimited output to an object first, then sort.

```
function dps {
    docker ps --format "table {{.Names}}\t{{.ID}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Ports}}" | 
       ConvertFrom-Csv -delimiter  "`t" |Sort-Object Names
}
```

Should return this:

```
NAMES       CONTAINER ID STATUS                  PORTS
-----       ------------ ------                  -----
database_A  27b33272e64c Up 15 hours             3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
database_B  1b1662223f17 Up 15 hours             33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33640->3306/tcp
database_C  8f98fc0890cc Up 15 hours             3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
framework_A a0d829729c8e Up 15 hours (unhealthy) 5050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5170->80/tcp
service_A   8708aec85ea7 Up 15 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5100->8080/tcp
service_B   7931365f450e Up 15 hours (unhealthy) 5160/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5160->80/tcp
service_C   e9b9272011d8 Up 15 hours (unhealthy) 5160/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5110->80/tcp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using same output without headers:

```
docker ps --format "{{.Names}}\t{{.ID}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Ports}}" | Sort-Object
```